# Set html cell contents to bold in Flex Table

Tags: java, gwt

I want to Set html  cell contents to bold in Flex Table.

```
FlexTable myTable = new FlexTable();
myTable.setHTML(1, 0, "Name :");
```

I want to make the "Name" content as Bold like '**Name**' instead of 'Name' . For now it is just displaying as Regular Text.

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: How about "<b>Name</b>"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

`FlexTable myTable = new FlexTable(); myTable.setHTML(1, 0, "<b>Name :</b>");` ?

Comment: that's exactly what I wrote in my comment.

Comment: You must have wrote it as I was editing it. Will delete in a few then.

Comment: FWIW, <strong> is preferred over <b>, though I often use <b> out of laziness :-)